# Wordpress Custom Post Type Pagination - /page/2/ not found

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

This is driving me crazy. I've tried every solution I could find but still not working for me.

I have a custom post type.

```
/**
 * Videos Custom Post Type
 */
function videos_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'videos', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Videos',
            'singular_name' => 'Video',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Video',
            'add_new' => 'Add New Video',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Video',
            'new_item' => 'New Video',
            'all_items' => 'All Videos'
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'videos' ),
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-video'
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'videos_post_type' );
```

Everything is working fine except pagination on the 'Archive' page. Pagination links are showing up properly but when I click on "Next", it ends in page not found error.

```
<div class="ast-row">
        <?php

            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            $loop = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'videos',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'orderby'=> 'menu_order',
            'paged'=> $paged
            ) );

            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                $loop->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="ast-col-md-4">
                    <?php echo the_content(); ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>

        </div>
        <div class="ast-row">
            <?php
                echo paginate_links( array(
                   'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
               ) );
            ?>
        <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div>
```

Also tried the following to echo_paginate_links()

```
                $big = 999999999; 
                echo paginate_links( array(
                   'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
                   'format' => '?paged=%#%',
                   'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
                   'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
               ) );
```

Moreover-
* I have tried to save permalink 
* I have tried to change permalink structure 
* I have tried query_posts instead of WP_Query
---none of these worked.

I should also mention that I have not created a single-videos.php template (because I don't need it for this post type) but I don't think that has anything to do with this issue. Please correct me if I am wrong. I just can't get my head around it. I'm using the Astra theme if that helps.

Please share your suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try below (replace your html)

```
<?php
          global $loop;
          $query = $query ? $query : $loop;
          $big = 999999999;

          $paginate = paginate_links( array(
            'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
            'type' => 'array',
            'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
            'format' => '?paged=%#%',
            'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
            'prev_previous'  =>('&larr; Older posts'),
            'prev_next'          => ( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ),
            'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
            'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
          ));
          if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) :
        ?>

        <div class="paginate">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <?php
              foreach ( $paginate as $page ) {
                echo '<li>' . $page . '</li>';
              }
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
         <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem recently. Not sure what the problem was but this worked for me.

```
$pagination = [
    'base' => @add_query_arg('paged','%#%'),
    'format' => '',
    'total' => $the_query->max_num_pages,
    'current' => get_query_var('paged') ?? 1,
    'show_all' => false,
    'mid_size' => 4,
    'type' => 'list',
    'next_text' => '&raquo;',
    'prev_text' => '&laquo;'
];
echo paginate_links($pagination);
```

Comment: So odd, I also tried out your code on a custom post type of mine and worked just fine. I know thats really unhelpful ha ha.

Comment: It's super weird. I wonder if it has anything to do with the Theme I'm using.

Comment: Just as a workaround try changing all your query vars to like "_paged" and see if it makes a diff. @KhairulAlam

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$big = 999999999; 
            echo paginate_links( array(
               'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', get_pagenum_link( $big ) ),
               'format' => '?paged=%#%',
               'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
               'total' => $loop->max_num_pages
           ) );
```

With

```
  global $loop;
  $query = $query ? $query : $loop;
  $big = 999999999;

  $paginate = paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'type' => 'array',
    'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'prev_previous'  =>('&larr; Older posts'),
    'prev_next'          => ( 'Newer posts &rarr;' ),
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
  ));
  if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) :
```

If Not Works I have Another Solusationn Just Ask me

Comment: Can you please explain the full implementation. I tried to implement it but got a string to array conversion error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and just figured out that the cause of my problem is that I had set the same slug to my Custom Post Type and the page showing the new WP_Query.

Hope it will be helpful.